# HTML 5 for DFP Doubleclick

Tags: jquery, macros, double-click

I have a jQuery fading slideshow I have created for mobile that will be displayed by DGP DoubleClick for Publishers. I first made sure that everything worked by submitting it as a tag with no HREFs. Because this is advertising I would really like to have a different URL for each image, and of course being advertising, this needs to be tracked. My two ideas were to use Google Analytics, and have each URL use this

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'campaign', 'Click1', 'offer1']); etc.
```

Having submitted my jQuery slideshow in that format, I have been told by AdOps (they are newbies at DFP) that does not work. I was sent a screenshot of the error message.

> Sorry, we don't recognize this tag. If you want to track clicks via DFP and avoid  counting discrepancies, you must insert macros manually.

Is a macro just something I add to the URL?

My other idea was to use a clickTracking URL creating by Google. AdOps is telling me they read that you can not use a clickTracking URL in DFP, and I have not submitted one for testing, but due to the newbiness and not really tech savvy nature of the person telling me this, I was hoping someone here might know if that is actually true.

Mainly seeking ideas and suggestions. If I can't track a different URL for each image it won't be a deal killer but it would be sweet.

Answer (score 0):

First off, a macro in DFP is something that you put in a creative (either in a creative snippet or in one of a few specific fields) that expands to something else. It could be a string, number,URL, etc. depending on which macro you're using. Here's a list of macros available in DFP Premium: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1242718?hl=en

If you want to track clicks on each image in your slideshow, you can't do this directly in DFP alone using a normal method. Normally for trafficking a 3rd party or custom creative in DFP, you will need to use the click macro in your anchor link to track any clicks directly within DFP. However, when you do this, the click tracker link will attribute all clicks using this macro to this creative. Thus if you use the click macro for each of the image links, they will all get attributed to the same creative and you won't be able to tell how many clicks each image in your slideshow is getting. If you just want to track the total clicks directly in DFP, then you can use the click macro in each of your links. Otherwise, a click macro isn't necessary in the DFP creative. Note that you probably won't see any clicks in DFP reporting if you don't use the click macro.

To track clicks on each individual image in the creative, you will need to use some other way to do track each of them. Both of your ideas should work. For #1, that should work but you will have to do all the reporting in Google Analytics. This technically won't work in tracking clicks in DFP since DFP won't be tracking any clicks this way without the click macros. However, if your goal is just to have these clicks reportable from somewhere (in this case Google Analytics), this should serve your purpose.

Your second idea should work as well. You'd have to create a click tracking line item for each of the images you want to track but you can grab each of the URLs from each line item and use it as the link for the images in the original slideshow creative. You'll have to report on each of the click tracking line items instead of the slideshow line item though, so a little extra work but this should also serve your purpose. Here are instructions on how to create a click tracking line item in case it's helpful: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1212244?hl=en.